# Vuejs calling a method from $on event

Tags: javascript, events, methods, vuejs2

Am building a vuejs component

```
methods: {
       filterPeople: function() {
        console.log('hello')
         //do some good stuff
       },


    },
    beforeCreate() {
     //do some ajax stuff

  },
    mounted() {
      Event.$on('applied', function() {
        console.log('the event is being caught')
        this.filterPeople();
      })
    })
```

The error I get is

```
this.filterPeople(); is not a function
```

When I move it outside the `Event.$on` block it does call the method.

How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use arrow functions to save the context:

`Event.$on('applied', () => this.filterPeople());`

Comment: Nice have not really done ES6 syntax but that looks tidy.

Answer (score 4):

It was all to do with Scope

```
 var self = this;
      Event.$on('applied', function() {
         self.filterPeople();
})
```